# Make jQuery.ajax() HTTP Request behave like a normal HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So, I'm using jQuery.ajax() to make a HTTP request and get an XML feed shown as plain text on my page.

Before this happens though, I prompt the user to type a word to be searched in that particular feed.

**The problem is that I want that word, if found, to be highlighted when it is shown as text on the user's window**, say for example have a background-color of red. I've tried everything but I can't seem to make it work, and I suspect because I need to parse it first in some way.

Here's the code:

```
function search(ans) {
var url = "SOME_XML_FEED"
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "html",
    crossDomain: "true",
    success: function (response) {
        var n = response.search(ans); //Where the word is found.
        var ansReplacement = '<p style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #ff0000">' + ans + '</p>';
        ans = response.replace(ans, ansReplacement);
        if (ans === response) {
            alert("The string was not found in a text with " + response.length + " letters.");
        } else {
            alert("The string was found at position: " + n + " in a text with " + response.length + " letters.");
        }
        $('#demo').text(ans);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well first of all you’ll want to switch from `.text()` to `.html()`, obviously ...

Comment: @CBroe Now, now. What's obvious to you may not be obvious to others. :)

Comment: agree with @George...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the "text" function to stick the HTML into "#demo" div. This strips out the html. Try using the "html" function instead:

```
        $('#demo').html(ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a global regex to find all occurrences of the string, then assign the modified HTML using jQuery's `.html()` method, not `.text()` :

```js
let toHighlight="in",
 $sampleText = $("#sampleText"),
 originalText = $sampleText.text(),
 highlightedText = originalText.replace(new RegExp(toHighlight, "gi"), `<span class="highlight">${toHighlight}</span>`)

$sampleText.html(highlightedText)
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ff0000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sampleText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tempus, sem at vehicula bibendum, magna arcu accumsan massa, eget porta velit odio ac lectus. Nullam erat sapien, consectetur in tortor eget, rhoncus commodo neque. Maecenas accumsan molestie arcu ac scelerisque. Etiam molestie velit in dolor rutrum, at vehicula mauris volutpat. Ut lobortis dui in maximus elementum. Maecenas quis orci non ligula lobortis aliquam.</div>
```